# iOS - own VoIP Asterisk client app

Tags: ios, swift, asterisk, voip

Recently I've started making a **client VoIP app** from scratch in **swift**. I have **Asterisk server** and i want to **receive incoming calls** (doesn't need to handle outgoing calls) from Asterisk (not from iOS users). How can I implement **handling VoIP calls and signalisation** (register, reject call) using native tools? If it's impossible to register to a VoIP account with CallKit and PushKit - what would be the best **open source** solution? I've never made an app for iOS and don't know all capabilites of CallKit and PushKit yet.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. I suggest you go back re-read the [tour] pages to get an idea of how to ask a good question.  Unfortunately your question is too broad and asking for off-site recommendations. iOS development can be complex and implementing a SIP client from scratch is quite ambitious for a first project.

Comment: Thank You for response. I thought make VoIP client app wouldn't be so hard. I wanted to build it based on Speakerbox from Apple. If I understand correctly, to handle incoming call from Asterisk I need to:
1) Generate VoIP certificate from Apple site
2) Connect this certificate to AGI on Asterisk (e.g. in PHP)
3) Somehow make a redirection from Asterisk to PHP script that will inform iOS about incoming call
4) Use PushRegister for informing about incoming call, registering in Asterisk, redirecting voice to Asterisk
Would it be enough to handle VoIP communication?

Comment: No, that just provides an out-of-band alerting merchandise. You need to provide a SIP stack to provide call supervision and endpoint registration and RTSP to handle media streaming. You also need to create UI elements. I strong,y suggest you search for some tutorials on iOS programming in swift to get started.

Answer (score 0):

CallKit is for front-end functionality of calling apps. It will not help you with connecting a client to your server. If you have never made an iOS app before then making a VOIP app is probably not the best place to start. You will almost certainly have to make your client from scratch unless Asterisk has a library for iOS.

Comment: Thanks. I thought that it will be simpler to develop... I'll be looking for open source ready-made solutions.